# How to pick out files in a folder in which the header contains specific text?

Tags: grep, ack

Use case: Let's say there is a folder full of large RDF+XML files and they follow different namespaces. We want to find those files that follow a given namespace (for example `xmlns:crm="http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm#"`).

Scanning files from top to bottom is time-consuming as a namespace is always defined in the first few lines of an XML file.

How to pick out files in a massive folder in which the header contains specific text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer looks something like this:

```
 awk '/hi/ { if (FNR >= 5) { nextfile }; print FNR, FILENAME }' *
```

Change the `/hi/` with your regex matching string. Change the `5` to be the last line number in the header you want to look at.

Comment: You've got your logic backward. You're only checking for `FNR > 5` in lines that match the pattern.

Comment: `nextfile` requires GNU awk or recent versions of `mawk`.

Comment: Interesting, I was looking at this ``http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/`` and it has `nextfile`. Will fix readability.

Comment: Indeed. While `nextfile` was introduced by GNU `awk`, Brian Kernighan (the `k` in `awk`) added it in his implementation in 1996, and that eventually made its way to the BSD `awk`s. Which means `nextfile` is more widely available than I initially thought (still not POSIX or available in many commercial Unices though).

Answer (score 1):

To look in the first 5 lines only, if your `awk` supports `nextfile`:

```
TEXT='xmlns:crm="http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm#"' \
  find . -type f -exec awk '
     index($0, ENVIRON["TEXT"]) {print FILENAME; nextfile}
     FNR == 5 {nextfile}' {} +
```

(if your `awk` doesn't support `nextfile`, that will be silently ignored and the files will be read fully).

Or you could use `perl`:

```
TEXT='xmlns:crm="http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm#"' \
  find . -type f -exec perl -Tne '
     if (index($_, $ENV{"TEXT"}) >= 0) {print "$ARGV\n"; close ARGV}
     elsif ($. == 5) {close ARGV}' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your files have a namespace declaration, With GNU/FreeBSD/OSX grep or any implementation that has the `-m` option, you can look for the namespace declaration and quit as soon as it's found, then pipe the result into a second grep to get the namespace that you're interested in.

```
grep -m xmlns: *.xml  |grep 'xmlns:crm="http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm#"'
```

If some files lack a recognizable namespace declaration or some other pattern that says “quit”, use sed or awk instead to specify a quitting condition based on the line number. With sed, there's no way to count lines per file, so you'll need to invoke sed on each file:

```
for x in *.xml; do
  if [ -n "$(sed -n -e 's/.*xmlns:crm="http:\/\/www.cidoc-crm.org\/cidoc-crm#".*/1/' -e '/xmlns:/q' -e '5q')" ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$x"
  fi
done
```

See [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169881) for an awk solution.

Any method based on text processing tools is [inherently fragile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). For example, it would pick up a namespace declaration that's commented out. Unless you're going to review the results manually or you know that all your files have a “tame” structure (no comments, no payload text that looks like what you're searching, etc.), you should use a proper XML parser instead — but it will be slower.